# How to create an activity profile with scroll and its name in the middle not on the left

Tags: android

How to create an activity profile with scroll and its name in the middle not on the left. i'am a new android development, and i want to make a profile activity like facebook, the title name in the middle, and can chan that title name, how to do this? Thank you very much

Comment: first go through some basic android tutorial.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: can you provide the code , what you tried so far.